# Why slideDown animation is automatically going for slideUp animation first?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am adding few results on click of a button. I am using `slideDown` method to show these new results, but no idea why these new results first `slideUp` and then perform a `slideDown` animation. And when I clear added results, it is removed instantly with no animation at all.

Please have a look on this demo: http://jsbin.com/imulem

```
$('#sb').click ( function(){
var html = '';

  html += "<div class='result'>" + 'fake results.. ' +  '</div>';
  html += "<div class='result'>" + 'fake results.. ' +  '</div>';
  html += "<div class='result'>" + 'fake results.. ' +  '</div>';
  $(html).hide().prependTo('#searchresults').slideDown('slow');
        });


$('#clearb').click ( function(){
            $('#searchresults>div').slideUp('slow').remove();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave to `.result` a class named `h0` which has `height: 0px;` property. This way they have no height when you click `#sb`. You should remove `div`s after animation ends.

For chrome problem, change the transition from `all` to `background-color`.

You can find working case [here](http://jsbin.com/imulem/4).

CSS

```
.h0 { height: 0px; }
#searchresults .result{
  padding: 1.2em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  color: #690011;
  border-radius: 1.8em;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #F0B616;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('#sb').click ( function(){
  var html = '';

  html += "<div class='result h0'>" + 'fake results.. ' +  '</div>';
  html += "<div class='result h0'>" + 'fake results.. ' +  '</div>';
  html += "<div class='result h0'>" + 'fake results.. ' +  '</div>';
  $(html).hide().prependTo('#searchresults').slideDown('slow');
});


$('#clearb').click ( function(){
  var $divs = $('#searchresults>div');
  $divs.slideUp('slow', function() { $divs.remove(); });
});
```

Comment: this script has the same problem in chrome

Comment: There, fixed chrome problem. :)

Comment: Looks like there was no need of `h0` ( Using safari ). Just changed the transition from `all` to `background-color` and worked like charm :) . Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This css is causing it:

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: But I need this for mouseover effect.